# How to - alert ,in jquery ajax form, after successful form submission?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit a PHP form, via `jquery $.ajax();` . Its submitting successfully, but when I am trying to alert a message- `alert(SUCCESS);` on success. It's not. Any guesses ?

CODE :

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'basic_cms_manager_home_fb_form_submit.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if (typeof data.error === 'undefined') {
      // Success so call function to process the form
      alert("SUCCESS");
      console.log('SUCCESS: ' + data.success);
    } else {
      // Handle errors here
      console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
    }
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Handle errors here
    console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
  },
  complete: function() {
    // STOP LOADING SPINNER
  }
});
```

NOTE: I already tried : console.log(data); n other tricks. My question is why Alert is not working, when entire script is working and why it's giving parseerror?

Comment: Change `alert(SUCCESS);` to `alert("SUCCESS");`, or if you want to alert the contents of `data.success`, do: `alert(data.success)`

Comment: It was already there, sorry for mistake. I updated it. But issue is still there.

Comment: Does the console log work? Are you sure that the `data.error` is not present at all in the response? Or is it just empty? (then it won't be undefined). Do a `console.log(data)` before your if statements and update your question with the output.

Comment: console.log works, but it gives ParseError. But, data is submitted.

Comment: ParseError means the server isn't returning valid json. Check the network tab of your browser's dev tools to look at the response.

Comment: We still would need to see the contents of `data`. Do a `console.log(data)` before your if statements and update your question with the response.

Comment: do `console.log(data)` before the `alert()` call and post it here

Comment: If it's a json parse error, it won't hit the `success` callback at all. He needs to look at the network tab.

Comment: Here is the Response on console.log(data) : http://pasteboard.co/8rd3F6Z5p.png

Comment: Updated code was :  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {

                        console.log(data);
                        //if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
                        if(!data.error)
                        {
                            // Success so call function to process the form

                            
                            alert("success");
                            console.log('SUCCESS: ' + data.success);


                        }

Comment: @JasonP : Here is the Response on console.log(data) : pasteboard.co/8rd3F6Z5p.png

Comment: @PlatinumIndustries : Here is the Response on console.log(data) : pasteboard.co/8rd3F6Z5p.png

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : Here is the Response on console.log(data) : pasteboard.co/8rd3F6Z5p.png

Comment: @luna.romania In your screenshot, see how the Headers tab is highlighted? Click the HTML tab instead and look at that. My guess is that the response is NOT json.

Answer (score 1):

SUCCESS is not a variable but a string. You need to put quotes around it like `alert("SUCCESS");`

Also the use of `.success` and `.error` methods have been deprecated. Use `.done` and `.fail` instead or you can simply do the following

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'basic_cms_manager_home_fb_form_submit.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {

    alert("SUCCESS");       
    console.log('SUCCESS: ' + data.success);

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
    // Handle errors here
    console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
    },
    complete: function()
    {
    // STOP LOADING SPINNER
    }
    });
```

Another thing

`Typeof null` returns an object, so if `data.errors` is null, your check will fail. Consider doing

```
if (!data.errors) {
    ...
}
```

if you want to persist with your code.

Comment: It was already there, sorry for mistake. I updated it. But issue is still there.

Comment: comment data type:"json" and than check

Comment: Do you see the console.log(data) in your success call.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I wonder, why u cannt see the code properly ? n stop marking my questions as duplicate, if u cannt solve or help, dont create troubles for me. OK.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that `data` is valid JSON
2. `data.error` is from the server, it might not be what you think it is. Use `console.log` to determine its true value. Further more, change it to something more meaningful like

> data.status => 'success' or 'fail'

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Remove - dataType:'json'; & send all data using - formdata.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Taz
 * Date: 9/29/2016
 * Time: 5:37 PM
 */
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax Image Upload Using PHP and jQuery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed|Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $("#uploadimage").on('submit',(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#message").empty();
                $('#loading').show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax_upload_image_submit.php", // Url to which the request is send
                    type: "POST",                       // Type of request to be send, called as method
                    data: new FormData(this),           // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
                    contentType: false,                 // The content type used when sending data to the server.
                    cache: false,                       // To unable request pages to be cached
                    processData:false,                  // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
                    success: function(data)             // A function to be called if request succeeds
                    {
                        $('#loading').hide();
                        $("#message").html(data);
                    }
                });
            }));

// Function to preview image after validation
            $(function() {
                $("#file").change(function() {
                    $("#message").empty(); // To remove the previous error message
                    var file = this.files[0];
                    var imagefile = file.type;
                    var match= ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/jpg"];
                    if(!((imagefile==match[0]) || (imagefile==match[1]) || (imagefile==match[2])))
                    {
                        $('#previewing').attr('src','noimage.png');
                        $("#message").html("<p id='error'>Please Select A valid Image File</p>"+"<h4>Note</h4>"+"<span id='error_message'>Only jpeg, jpg and png Images type allowed</span>");
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                    }
                });
            });
            function imageIsLoaded(e) {
                $("#file").css("color","green");
                $('#image_preview').css("display", "block");
                $('#previewing').attr('src', e.target.result);
                $('#previewing').attr('width', '250px');
                $('#previewing').attr('height', '230px');
            };
        });


    </script>

    <style>


        body {
            font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
        }
        h1
        {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #96DAD1;
            height: 70px;
            color: rgb(95, 89, 89);
            margin: 0 0 -29px 0;
            padding-top: 14px;

            font-size: 35px;
        }
        .main {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            left: 20%;
            width: 450px;
            height:530px;
            border: 2px solid gray;

        }
        .main label{
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.71);
            margin-left: 60px;
        }
        #image_preview{
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 30px;
            top: 100px;
            left: 100px;
            width: 250px;
            height: 230px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 180px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #C0C0C0;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        #selectImage{
            padding: 19px 21px 14px 15px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            width: 414px;
            background-color: #EDFCFF;

        }
        .submit{
            font-size: 16px;
            background: linear-gradient(#ffbc00 5%, #ffdd7f 100%);
            border: 1px solid #e5a900;
            color: #4E4D4B;
            font-weight: bold;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 300px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 10px 0;
            outline: none;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-left: 15%;
        }
        .submit:hover{
            background: linear-gradient(#ffdd7f 5%, #ffbc00 100%);
        }
        #file {
            color: red;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 5px solid #96DAD1;
            background-color: #96DAD1;
            margin-top: 10px;


            margin-left: 15%;
            width: 72%;
        }
        #message{
            position:absolute;
            top:120px;
            left:815px;
        }
        #success
        {
            color:green;
        }
        #invalid
        {
            color:red;
        }
        #line
        {
            margin-top: 274px;
        }
        #error
        {
            color:red;
        }
        #error_message
        {
            color:blue;
        }
        #loading
        {
            display:none;
            position:absolute;
            top:50px;
            left:850px;
            font-size:25px;
        }



    </style>





</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
    <h1>Facebook Update</h1><br/>
    <hr>
    <form id="uploadimage" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="image_preview"><img id="previewing" src="noimage.png" width="250" height="230" /></div>
        <hr id="line">
        <div id="selectImage">


            <label>Select Your Image</label><br/>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" required />

            <label>FB Link</label><br/>
            <input type="text" name="fb_link" id="fb_link" required />




            <label>Show/Hide Status</label><br/>
            <select name="show_fb" class="myselect" required>
                <option value="">---Select---</option>
                <option value="1">Show</option>
                <option value="0">Hide</option>
            </select>




            <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<h4 id='loading' >loading..</h4>
<div id="message"></div>
</body>
</html>
```